# knex query optimisation for batch insert / update transactions

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am new to knex.js for mysql queries, I have following three queries which take a long time to resolve. is there a better way to do the following

```
await db.transaction((trx) => {
    let queries = existingProductsArr.map((tuple) => {
        const id = tuple.id;
        delete tuple.id;
    
        return trx('product')
            .update(tuple)
            .where({ id })
            .transacting(trx);
    });
    
    let issueQueries = trx('product_issue')
        .insert(findings.map((tuple) => tuple))
        .onConflict('id')
        .merge()
        .transacting(trx)  

    let resolvedQueries = trx('product_issue')
        .whereIn(['asin', 'market', 'created_by'],
            resolvedFindings.map((rf) => ([rf.asin, rf.market, rf.created_by] ) 
        )).update({ is_resolved: 'yes' });

    return Promise.all([...queries, ...issueQueries, ...resolvedQueries])
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback);
});
```

All arrays in this question can be in thousands in lengths

Note: I'm open to use options like in-memory caches like redis and any other

Comment: I would suggest adding some logs and [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/time) to figure out what and which query exactly takes the longest time and focus on that first.

Comment: first query, because there are e.g. 2000 updated rows then it means 2000 queries

Comment: The actual SQL is important. It is possible to run a single "update" statement against MySQL which can update 2000 (or whatever number) of rows. There are many variables, factors, etc., but if running a single "update.." with 2,000 rows feels slow then something is definitely not right.

Answer (score 0):

(There are times when the platform gets in the way of making efficient use of the underlying database; this might be such a case.)

First, let me comment on what seems to be multiple threads using a single connection to the database -- That will not work.  If it is actually multiple connections, each performing one 'transaction', then I should point out that making a connection may take longer than the query to be performed.

Bottom line: Have a single connection and do the operations one at a time.

Please provide a sample of the *generated* SQL that you are trying to batch.

Now, let me comment on what SQL can do to "batch" statements.

It is certainly possible *in SQL* to insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (1,2), (33,44), (9,8);
```

Inserting 100 rows this way is 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERTs`.  So it is worth doing.

It is trickier to do a batch `UPDATE`.  One way is to generate a table with the update info, then do a multi-table UPDATE using that table.

Another way is to build an IODKU (upsert) that is "batched".  (It's a bit tricky.)

Sorry, cannot translate any of this into Knex.  If you need the raw SQL for the batched IODKU, let me know.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question; I will need some details from it.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use a node.js connector like MariaDB's node.js which supports batch operations. For MySQL databases the driver rewrites/optimizes your insert statement, for MariaDB databases it will use the bulk feature which allows to send insert/update/delete with only one roundtrip.

The [Documentation](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/batch.md) for MariaDB's node.js batch also contains a performance comparision between batch and single execution.